# Pi suddenly refuses ssh, udp

Tags: networking, ssh

I have a Pi 3B that until today was working fine on the local network, it has a fixed IP address, e.g. 192.168.0.25, and I can ping it, and I can ssh *from that Pi* to any other device on the network. But ssh the opposite way is not working any longer, nor is UDP which I use for OSC communication. I have several identically configured Pis, they all behave well. That particular machine was working fine all the time, and I didn't change anything to the configuration.

What could cause this? `ping 192.168.0.25` works fine, but `ssh -vvv pi@192.168.0.25` simply says

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u1, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.0.25" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.25 [192.168.0.25] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.0.25 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.25 port 22: Connection refused
```

and Open Sound Control messages via UDP simply don't arrive any longer. `sudo service ssh status` says ssh daemon is active and listening on port 22 (0.0.0.0). ifconfig confirms the IP address is set as I thought. I have no idea what's wrong now. My only idea now is to duplicate the SD image from one of the other Pis. But sure there must be an explanation.

Comment: Did you upgrade the OS on your Pi recently? I know that SSH is disabled by default now on Raspbian. Perhaps one or more of the new default settings are causing your issues.

Comment: No, I didn't, and I verified that ssh is enabled

Comment: Which distro do you have installed?

Comment: Raspbian Jessie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the outward going traffic was all working, I started to suspect that the problem might have not been the Pi but my laptop. So it turned out, I could use ssh from another Pi to this particular Pi without problem, confirming that it was a problem with the ssh client on my laptop that for some unknown reason could not connect to that particular IP (although it had no problem with others). After a while, magically all was working fine again.